# Pay-Per-Node Functionality

Tags: 8, nodes, commerce

My client would like a content type that has to be purchased by a registered user on a node-per-node basis.

A previously registered user will see a view with the available content they can purchase and then that user can purchase individual nodes. These nodes that have been purchased will also appear in a My Library view as well.

I have found multiple tutorials on how to do this via D7; however, I can't seem to find anything that shows how to do this on D8.

Can Drupal 8's [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) Module do this out of the box or will I need to install additional modules to reach this functionality.

I am trying to find the right configurations of Products, Orders, and Stores but so far to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

We're doing something similar.

1. The User gets a role, that determines what he may buy
2. A custom field on the productVariation lists which roles it is available for
3. In a preprocess function we compare the user's roles to the accepted roles on the variation and set a flag
4. twig evaluates that flag

Since we only have 5 products, where we have to differentiate, this works. I imagine if you had hundreds, it might be cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to handle this in Drupal 8 would be with [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license).